# react native undefined check not works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I check few datas like housenumber, street, city etc if that is undefined.

Why my If check not works If I want to check if the city is undefined?

```
${typeof el.properties.city !== "undefined" ? el.properties.city : ''}
```

el.properties.city in console.log is undefined. If I take the el.properties.city in the empty string then I get undefined. So its undefined but not work. He shows me the empty string

Comment: could you add a working sample ? ..

Comment: https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/ I use this if you map it you can try it. In other case it works but only not in city. And the city exists and is not "undefined" but it shows me undefined. But others city works. If I press keywords automatilly shows all citys execept one. Its not bad If one city not works. But its not good to see if a field is empty

Comment: The answers looks good.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the ternary operator and the optional chaining like this:

```
${el?.properties?.city ? el.properties.city : ""}
```

The optional chaining checks the objects itself if it contains null or undefined in properties or city. If it pass the test, it will return the object. Otherwise an empty string is returned.

You can do it also simple like this:

```
${el?.properties?.city || ""}
```

Comment: not working. he shows again the empty field

Answer (score 0):

please try this:: el.properties.hasOwnProperty("city")? el.properties.city : ""

Comment: not working. he shows again the empty field

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if the value equals `undefined`, but you are checking if the value equals `"undefined"`, which is a string.

Change the statement checking the actual `undefined` type:

```
${typeof el.properties.city !== undefined ? el.properties.city : ''}
```